# Correct syntax for MYSQL query to JSON_SET in Node

Tags: mysql, json

I need to set/update JSON array in MYSQL table from Node and I have this query, that throws a `Invalid JSON path expression` error.
For example I want to find object with key `2022-01-03` and if it exist update its value to `O 08:00`

```
UPDATE allemployees SET schedule = JSON_SET(schedule, '$.2022-01-03', 'O 08:00') WHERE name_cyr = 'John Doe'
```

My JSON in the table looks like this:

```
[{"2022-01-03": "H 08:00"}, [{"2022-01-04": "H 08:00"}] ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE allemployees
SET schedule = JSON_SET(schedule, '$[0]."2022-01-03"', 'O 08:00') 
WHERE name_cyr = 'John Doe';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c59600049b4dfc1675c444a6da578bb

1. The path `"2022-01-03"` contains dashes and **must** be enclosed with doublequote chars.
2. The value to be set is not upper-level value, it is a component of definite array element.